# Mutt Notify on Finish Sending

Tags: notify-send, mutt

I'm looking for a way in `.muttrc` to tell it to invoke `notify-send` when it's done sending an email. I use Mutt inside a Guake window. So when I hit `y` to send I immediately hit `F12` to close the terminal and get back to work.

I need a way for Mutt to invoke `notify-send` after it's done sending so I know it's done sending.